# Tengo un arrayList de arrayList, y quiero encontrar un numero registrado pero cuando corro el ciclo este no para en donde se encuentra el registro

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package Lista;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListMultidimensional {
    
    private final Scanner entra = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Object dato,matricula;
    private String columna = "si";
    private String fila = "si";
    private int i=0;
    private final ArrayList <ArrayList<Object>> array2 = new ArrayList();
    
    public void bidiArrayList2(){
        System.out.println("\n\nIntroduce datos por lista, 'no' pra terminar");
```

voy recorriendo el arrayList que contiene los demas arraylist que apenas serán agregados, en esta parte solo es registro de la info

```
        while(fila.equals("si")){
            array2.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

creamos el objeto, espacio para la lista simple, fila

```
            System.out.println("Registro Alumnos " + i);

            array2.get(i).add(this.matricula(i));
            
            System.out.println("Nombre: ");
            dato = entra.next();
            array2.get(i).add(dato);
            
            System.out.println("Agregar Alumno: ");
            fila = entra.next();
            columna = "si";
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Esta es la función en la que tengo problema, ya intenté de varias maneras pero en ninguna me imprime los datos que hay correspondientes a la matricula, como está el código ahorita manda un error del cast

```
    public void buscaMatricula(){
        System.out.println("Matricula a buscar: ");
        int matricula1 = entra.nextInt();
        
        for(int i=0; i<array2.size(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<array2.get(i).size();j++){
                int cambio1 = (int)array2.get(i).get(j);
                if(cambio1 == matricula1){
                    System.out.print(array2.get(i).get(j) + " SI");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(".");
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Hola pppekas, bienvenido, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a corregir errores.

```
System.out.println("Registro Alumnos " + i);
    array2.get(i).add( this.matricula(i) );
```

Acá tenemos un fallo grave: declaras ***Object matricula***, y luego le pides un valor con ***matricula(i)***; es decir, no solo nunca instanciaste ***matricula***, sino que tampoco es un array.

Supongo que lo correcto es:

```
array2.get(i).add( i );  // "i" sería el número de matrícula
```

Luego tenemos:

```
    System.out.println( "Agregar Alumno: " );
    fila = entra.next();
    columna = "si";   // no me queda claro que cumpla alguna función.
    i++;
```

Ahora, en buscar:

```
    int matriculaBuscada = entra.nextInt();        
    for( int i = 0; i < array2.size(); i++ ) {
          // quité, el 2° for, porque sabemos que lo buscado está en la posición "0".
        int matricula = (int) array2.get(i).get(0);
        if( matriculaBuscada == matricula ){
                  // con get(1) imprimimos el nombre
                System.out.print( array2.get(i).get(1) + " SI");
                return;
            }
        }
     }
```

La clase completa sería:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListMultidimensional {

   private final Scanner entra = new Scanner( System.in );
   private Object dato, matricula;
   private String columna = "si";
   private String fila = "si";
   private int i = 0;
   private final ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> array2 = new ArrayList();

   public void bidiArrayList2() {
      System.out.println( "\n\nIntroduce datos por lista, 'no' pra terminar" );
      fila = entra.next();
      while( fila.equals( "si" ) ) {
         array2.add( new ArrayList<>() );
         System.out.println( "Registro Alumnos " + i );
         array2.get( i ).add( i );
         
         System.out.println("Nombre: ");
         dato = entra.next();
         array2.get(i).add( dato );
         
         System.out.println( "Si quiere agregar otro alumno, escriba 'si' " );
         fila = entra.next();
         i++;
      }
   }

   public void buscaMatricula() {
      System.out.println( "Matricula a buscar:" );
      int matriculaBuscada = entra.nextInt();

      for( int i = 0; i < array2.size(); i++ ) {
         int matricula = (int) array2.get( i ).get( 0 );
         if( matriculaBuscada == matricula ) {
            System.out.print( array2.get( i ).get( 1 ) + " SI" );
            return;
         }
      }
      System.out.println ( "No tenemos ese número de matrícula" ); 
   }   
   
   public static void main( String[] arg ) {
      ArrayListMultidimensional almd = new ArrayListMultidimensional();
      almd.bidiArrayList2();
      almd.buscaMatricula();
   }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, en la parte de this.matricula(i) era una función que quité porque no tenía mucho que ver con la pregunta, pero muchas gracias por la corrección :D

Comment: @pppekas, un placer ayudarte!!.